# Get part of String which was not truncated by ellipsize

Tags: android

How to get part of String which weren't truncated in multiline TextView. For instance if I have "This is some text which is quite long as you see" and TextView would show "This is some text which is..." then I want to get that second String into some variable. What is easiest way to do so?

Comment: do you want truncated part or not truncated part?as per your example,I think you need truncated part and I have answered in that way.

Comment: The answer by @MehulJoisar (or a derivative of it) is what you need if you have a single-line text view.  For multi-line text views that code will not work.  I finally managed to come up with the code that works for a multi-line text view - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to get it by effectively computing the ellipsised string yourself, something like this:

```
String ellipsised = TextUtils.ellipsize(textView.getText(),
                                        textView.getPaint(),
                                        (float)textView.getWidth(),
                                        TextUtils.TruncateAt.END).toString();
```

This may not be the best approach, but it should work.  `ellipsize` method isn't documented very well, so I'm not sure what it expects as the *available width* parameter (float), but looking through some source code it seems that it's the width of the text view.

**UPDATE:** Just tested this code.  It works perfectly when the ellipsised truncation is in one line.  If you specify `maxLines` on your original text view, then some other hack is needed.

**UPDATE 2:** After some struggle, I managed to write a method to get exact ellipsised text from a multiline wrapped textview.  It's a lot more complex, but it does produce correct results.

```
private String getEllipsisedText(TextView textView) {
    String text = textView.getText().toString();
    int lines = textView.getLineCount();
    int width = textView.getWidth();
    int len = text.length();
    TextUtils.TruncateAt where = TextUtils.TruncateAt.END;
    TextPaint paint = textView.getPaint();

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    int spos = 0, cnt, tmp, hasLines = 0;

    while(hasLines < lines - 1) {
        cnt = paint.breakText(text, spos, len, true, width, null);
        if(cnt >= len - spos) {
            result.append(text.substring(spos));
            break;
        }

        tmp = text.lastIndexOf('\n', spos + cnt - 1);

        if(tmp >= 0 && tmp < spos + cnt) {
            result.append(text.substring(spos, tmp + 1));
            spos += tmp + 1;
        }
        else {
            tmp = text.lastIndexOf(' ', spos + cnt - 1);
            if(tmp >= spos) {
                result.append(text.substring(spos, tmp + 1));
                spos += tmp + 1;
            }
            else {
                result.append(text.substring(spos, cnt));
                spos += cnt;
            }
        }

        hasLines++;
    }

    if(spos < len) {
        result.append(TextUtils.ellipsize(text.subSequence(spos, len), paint, (float)width, where));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Note that this code assume that the ellipses are at the end.  It shouldn't be too difficult to modify it to cater for other `ellipsize` options.

Comment: Will not always work because we need to also take into account padding of a view. Therefore width must be calculated by following: 

  int width = textView.getWidth() - textView.getPaddingLeft() - textView.getPaddingRight();

      Aleks G, thank you very much for your solution.

Comment: I think the second occurrence of `spos += tmp + 1;` is wrong and should be `spos = tmp + 1;`. Maybe also the first one.

Comment: @Revolutionair why don't you test it? I ran my code before posting the answer, so I am fairly sure it works correctly as is

Comment: @AleksG I tested it and your version doesn't work as intended. It worked when I changed it

Comment: Thanks @AyazAlifov I test and see it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

**Original String:**

```
String mVeryLongString = "abcd dfjdsfjdslf jsdlkfjkdf jkdsfj ksdf jkdfjdkf jkfdjfkd fdkjfdkjf dkjfkdjfk dkjfjdkf dkjfkdjfkdj";
```

**Truncated Part:**

```
String mTruncatedPart = (String) tvLongName.getText().subSequence(tvLongName.getLayout().getEllipsisStart(0), tvLongName.getText().length());
```

**Note:**
use your textview's name instead of `tvLongName`

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: I just tested your code - and it always returns the entire string, not the truncated or untruncated parts.

Comment: Did some more testing.  This works perfectly fine for `android:singleLine="true"`, but does not work if I have multiple lines in the text view with ellipses.